# Unselect items in a jquery selection object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a JQuery selection Object

```
someItems = $(".someClass")
```

What I want to do is "unselecting" an item. So for exemple, if the previous query has a result of 3 `select`, I want to remove the second one frome the set. So it will remain 2 `select` but the unselected one have not been removed from the DOM. Is there any JQuery way to do this or I have to build my own funtion for it ?

Example :

```
someItems = $(".someClass")
someItems.remove(someItems.first())
```

Comment: It is possible to unselect an option. I don't understand the 'previous query' part. Could you please try to clarify with maybe a better example.

Comment: I don't want to unselect an option, I want to "filter" the Jquery Matched Set, removing a given item from the Set.

Comment: Then use `filter()`.  What criteria determine what is to remain selected?

Comment: I want to unselect one of the item of the item. So remain selected all others items.

Comment: Yes, but which one?  An arbitrary one?  A random one? The second one?  That's the piece of information that's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with the [jquery not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method.

```
someItems = $(".someClass")

//It's for the example, You can have it for exemple in an event handler
toDelete = someItems.get(2)

someItems = someItems.not(toDelete)
//Now someItems don't contains toDelete.
```

Comment: I will try but it's perhaps what I was searching for :-)

Answer (score 0):

The resulting list of items is just an array. So you can use `splice`.

```
someItems = $(".someClass")
someItems.splice(0, 1)
someTtems //now missing the first element
```

Comment: Yes I know... But how to determine the first argument ? I don't have the position of my item in the matched set, I only have the item.